# Need help to create class Counter in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a task to create a programm which get a number from 0 to 999. Methods that should be realized in it. 1. too display this object. 2. to plus 1 for number. 3. to minus 1 from number. 4. to minus whatever number from  original number. I've done all of then except last one. In m program it stand's for "o"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

 using namespace std;

class Schetchik
{
public:
Schetchik(int val)
{
    if (val < 0 || val > 999)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not right symbol");

    counter = val;
}

void process_plus()
{
    counter++;
    if (counter > 999)
        counter = 0;
}

void process_minus()
{
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0)
        counter = 999;
}
void process_minusnumber(int m)
{
    counter = counter - m;
    if (counter < 0)
        counter = 999;
}
void process_c()
{
    counter = 0;
}

int get_pokazanie()
{
    return counter;
}

private:
int counter;
};

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "English");
int n;
int m;
cout << "input number: ";
cin >> n;
auto schet = Schetchik(n);
while (1)
{
    char opt;
    cout << "input+, c, -, o, l or e for exit: ";
    cin >> opt;
    if (opt != 'e')
    {
        if (opt == '+')
        {
            schet.process_plus();
        }
        else if (opt == 'c')
        {
            schet.process_c();
        }
        else if (opt == 'l')
        {
            cout << "Show number " << schet.get_pokazanie() << endl;
        }
        else if (opt == '-')
        {
            schet.process_minus();
        }
        else if (opt == 'o')
        {
            cout << "input number for minus ";
            cin >> m;
            schet.process_minusnumber(m);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not right symbol!" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Exit";
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass the variable `m` to `process_minusnumber` as an argument, and subtract that value from `counter`.

Comment: @cigien so i need to put `int m` into process but how i would output (`cin`) it or minus from original number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is pass the 'number for minus' to the method that is going to do the subtraction.

```
    else if (opt == 'o')
    {
        cout << "input number for minus ";
        cin >> m;
        schet.process_minusnumber(m);  // <-- change here
```

Then you need to write `process_minusnumber` so that it takes this number as a parameter

```
void process_minusnumber(int number)
{
    ... // do calculation here using number
}
```

Writing functions with *parameters* is a basic skill in programming. Any time information need to pass from one function to another a parameter is usually the way to do it.

**EDIT**

So here's the correct way to write `process_minusnumber`

```
void process_minusnumber(int number)
{
    counter -= number;
    while (counter < 0)
        counter += 1000;
}
```

I am assuming that number is always positive. If `number` could be negative then you might also need to adjust for counter begin greater than 999.